# How to iterate a HashMap with primefaces selectable datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, facelets, uirepeat

I have tried different solutions but none is working in my case. I want all the rows in this datatable to be selectable. The problem seems to be the `<ui:repeat`that is probably overriding the objects...

My bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Chat {

    private static Map<String, List<ChatObject>> chat = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<ChatObject>>();
    private ChatObject selectedChatObject;

    public void onChatRowSelection(){
        if(getSelectedChatObject() != null){
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    }

    public List<Map.Entry<String, List<ChatObject>>> getChatList() {
        Set<Map.Entry<String, List<ChatObject>>> productSet = chat.entrySet();
        return new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, List<ChatObject>>>(productSet);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstructMethod() { 

        if(chat.isEmpty()){

            List<ChatObject> objectsList1 = new ArrayList<ChatObject>();
            objectsList1.add(new ChatObject("3369818", "1", "1"));
            objectsList1.add(new ChatObject("3369819", "2", "2"));
            objectsList1.add(new ChatObject("3369820", "3", "3"));

            chat.put("Chat Topic 1", objectsList1);

            List<ChatObject> objectsList2 = new ArrayList<ChatObject>();        
            objectsList2.add(new ChatObject("3369813", "4", "4"));
            objectsList2.add(new ChatObject("3369815", "5", "5"));
            chat.put("Chat Topic 2", objectsList2);
        }

    }

    public ChatObject getSelectedChatObject() {
        return selectedChatObject;
    }

    public void setSelectedChatObject(ChatObject selectedChatObject) {
        this.selectedChatObject = selectedChatObject;
    }
}
```

My JSF:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">

<h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" acceptcharset="ISO-8859-1">

<ui:repeat value="#{chat.chatList}" var="chatEntry">

    <h2><h:outputText value="#{chatEntry.key}" /></h2>
    <br />

    <p:dataTable 
        value="#{chatEntry.value}" 
        var="chatEntryVar"
        widgetVar="chatTableWV" 
        styleClass="geralBorderless"
        style="cursor:pointer" 
        rowKey="#{chatEntryVar.id}" 
        rendered="true"
        selectionMode="single" 
        selection="#{chat.selectedChatObject}"
        paginatorAlwaysVisible="false">

        <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
            listener="#{chat.onChatRowSelection}" 
            oncomplete="chatTableWV.unselectAllRows();">

        </p:ajax>

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{chatEntryVar.name}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

</ui:repeat>
</h:form>
</html>
```

All the 5 `ChatObject` in my Map are successfully shown in my page. But `onChatRowSelection` method **will** only print "test" when I click in the rows related to the **second** list I added to my map: `objectList2`. **When I click in the lines from the first list I added** `objectList1`, when the system enters in the `onChatRowSelection` method, `selectedChatObject` will be null. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
<ui:repeat ...>
    <p:dataTable ... widgetVar="chatTableWV">
       <p:ajax ... oncomplete="chatTableWV.unselectAllRows();">
```

Multiple data tables are been assigned exactly the same `widgetVar` name in JavaScript scope. In effects, the following JavaScript code is generated:

```
window['chatTableWV'] = new Widget(tableElement1);
window['chatTableWV'] = new Widget(tableElement2);
window['chatTableWV'] = new Widget(tableElement3);
// ...
```

Basically, every iteration overrides the last object assigned to the declared `widgetVar` name until it ends up referencing the last one. All widgets expect of the last one are basically unavailable, causing them to not be functional anymore as to row selection.

Fix it accordingly by giving them each an unique `widgetVar`. You could use the iteration index of `<ui:repeat>` for this.

```
<ui:repeat ... varStatus="loop">
    <p:dataTable ... widgetVar="chatTableWV_#{loop.index}">
       <p:ajax ... oncomplete="chatTableWV_#{loop.index}.unselectAllRows();">
```

This way the following JavaScript code is generated:

```
window['chatTableWV_0'] = new Widget(tableElement1);
window['chatTableWV_1'] = new Widget(tableElement2);
window['chatTableWV_2'] = new Widget(tableElement3);
// ...
```

And finally PrimeFaces widget manager can find them all.

Comment: Thanks!!! I tried to put a dynamic id in the datatable but it was not possible.. never thought about the widgetVar. Tonight I'll test it!