# Using multiple FluidGrids in one form

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-extensions

I am working on creating a dynamic form using Primefaces 5.2, FluidGrid (PrimeFaces Extensions 3.1.0)

I have my form in several sub sections so I create a `private HashMap<PDIDefinition, List<FluidGridItem>> formItems;` where `PDIDefinition` represents one section of the form.

In my view i then:

```
<ui:repeat var="pdi" value="#{FormGenerator.formItems.keySet().toArray()}" id="all">

        <p:panel header="#{pdi.getFragmentDefinition().getFragmentName()}" style="margin-bottom:1em; width:100%;">

            <pe:fluidGrid id="fluidGrid" value="#{FormGenerator.formItems.get(pdi)}" var="data"
                          hGutter="20" vGutter="10" widgetVar="fluidGridWdgt" 
                          >
                <pe:fluidGridItem type="stringValue" >
                    <div class="dynaFormLabel">
                        <p:outputLabel for="txt" value="#{data.label}"/>
                    </div>
                    <p:inputText id="txt" value="#{data.value}" />
                </pe:fluidGridItem>
                <pe:fluidGridItem type="integerValue">
                    <div class="dynaFormLabel">
                        <p:outputLabel for="int" value="#{data.label}"/>
                    </div>
                    <p:spinner id="int" value="#{data.value}" />
                </pe:fluidGridItem>
                <pe:fluidGridItem type="dateValue" styleClass="calendar">
                    <div class="dynaFormLabel">
                        <p:outputLabel for="cal" value="#{data.label}"/>
                    </div>
                    <p:calendar id="cal" value="#{data.value}" showOn="button"/>
                </pe:fluidGridItem>
            </pe:fluidGrid>
        </p:panel>
    </ui:repeat>

    <p:commandButton action="#{FormGenerator.saveValues}" process="form"/>
```

As you can see I add a Panel for each section and then add a fluidGrid for each section.

My probölem however is that the data in the backend is only stored for the last fluidGrid not for all. I have checked the network log of chrome and can see that all values are submitted to the server.

So my question: How can I ensure that all the data on the server is updated.
Or: Is there a way I can group the elements within a single FluidGrid?

More information from the backing bean (item creation process):

```
private void generateModel() {

    fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    fragmentValues = new ArrayList<>();
    formItems = new HashMap<>();
    fields = new ArrayList<>();

    for (PDIDefinition pdid : pdiDefinitions) {

        Fragment f = new Fragment();
        f.setDefinition(pdid.getFragmentDefinition());
        fragments.add(f);
        List<FluidGridItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
        formItems.put(pdid, items);

        for (FragmentValueDefinition fvd : f.getDefinition().getFragmentValues()) {

            FragmentValue fv = new FragmentValue();
            fv.setFragmentValueDefinition(fvd);
            fv.setFragmentId(f.getInner());
            if (f.getValues() == null) {
                f.setValues(new ArrayList<>());
            }
            f.getValues().add(fv);
            fragmentValues.add(fv);
            DynamicField df = new DynamicField((fv));
            fields.add(df);
            if ("String".equals(fvd.getType())) {
                items.add(new FluidGridItem(df, "stringValue"));
            }
            if ("Integer".equals(fvd.getType())) {
                items.add(new FluidGridItem(df, "integerValue"));
            }
            if ("Date".equals(fvd.getType())) {
                items.add(new FluidGridItem(df, "dateValue"));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

---

**EDIT**

Changed the xhtml to reflect new findings: 
[<h:form> within <ui:repeat> not entirely working, only the last <h:form> is processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808878/hform-within-uirepeat-not-entirely-working-only-the-last-hform-is-proc)

However values of all but last iteration of `<p:dataList>` are not updated on server on submit (Values on Submit are reset on the client). Values of the last iteration are stored on the server.

```
   <p:dataList var="pdi" value="#{FormGenerator.formItems.keySet()}" id="all" varStatus="loop" type="none" >
        <p:panel id="panel" header="#{pdi.getFragmentDefinition().getFragmentName()}" style="margin-bottom:1em; width:100%;">
            <pe:fluidGrid  id="fluidGrid" value="#{FormGenerator.formItems[pdi]}" var="data"
                           hGutter="20" vGutter="10" >

                <pe:fluidGridItem type="stringValue"  id="txt_">
                    <div class="dynaFormLabel">
                        <p:outputLabel for="txt" value="#{FormGenerator.formItems[pdi][data.id].getData().label}"/>
                    </div>
                    <p:inputText id="txt" value="#{FormGenerator.formItems[pdi][data.id].getData().value}"/>
                </pe:fluidGridItem>
                <pe:fluidGridItem type="integerValue" id="int_">
                    <div class="dynaFormLabel">
                        <p:outputLabel for="int" value="#{FormGenerator.formItems[pdi][data.id].getData().label}"/>
                    </div>
                    <p:spinner id="int" value="#{FormGenerator.formItems[pdi][data.id].getData().value}" />
                </pe:fluidGridItem>
                <pe:fluidGridItem type="dateValue" id="cal_">
                    <div class="dynaFormLabel">
                        <p:outputLabel for="cal" value="#{FormGenerator.formItems[pdi][data.id].getData().label}"/>
                    </div>
                    <p:calendar id="cal" value="#{FormGenerator.formItems[pdi][data.id].getData().value}" showOn="button"/>
                </pe:fluidGridItem>

            </pe:fluidGrid>
        </p:panel>
    </p:dataList>
```

Partial POST request on submit as chrome shows me:

```
form:form
form:all:0:fluidGrid:txt:n
form:all:0:fluidGrid:TV5Wd2IL:txt:
form:all:0:fluidGrid:CYqNHGWx:int_input:
form:all:0:fluidGrid:Y6QIaH1C:cal_input:
form:all:1:fluidGrid:hvi81zhh:txt:k
form:all:1:fluidGrid:iY1YsIDm:txt:
form:all:2:fluidGrid:BA6slTyQ:txt:p
```

i had entered "n","k" and "p" to the input fields. only "p" was stored on the server.

Comment: you xhtml is not complete, it misses a `ui:repeat` open tag

Comment: Are you sure `fluidGrid` is the problem? You have tried not using it, and all values are stored when you don't?

Comment: Well I have noticed that no matter how many elements are created in the last loop, they all work. I guess it's something to do with the combuination of the ui:repeat and the FluidGrid. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27089830/how-to-iterate-a-hashmap-with-primefaces-selectable-datatatable it might be a duplicate widgetVar so i added `widgetVar="fluidGridWdgt_#{loop.index+1}"` but the loop.index is empty in the fluidGrid. loop is `varStatus="loop"` from the ui:repeat

Comment: p.S.: the `loop` variable is not empty outside of `pe:fluidGrid`

Comment: had a closer look wih fireBug and found, that the widgets are in fact created correctly. (each fluidGrid has it's own widget, and all form elements seem to be registered)

Comment: Seems to be related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678755/valuechange-listener-inside-uirepeat-only-works-for-the-last-repeated-component